# Best way to write custom flume NG source/sink

Tags: hadoop, flume

I am writing custom flume source and sink and currently I am not seeing a
best way to re-use the existing flume-ng code. For example, I am not able to
extend the AvroSource class and customize some functionality easily without
having to copy/paste a lot of existing code. Was it intended to be that way
or am I doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

You would only want to customize AvroSource if you wanted a source that accepted Avro messages. That would be a surprising reason to write a custom source and sink.

To write a custom sink follow the [custom sink docs](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeDeveloperGuide.html#sink). Custom source is in the same documentation.

BTW, why do you need a custom source and sink?

Lastly, 1.4.0 has just been released - you should use that if possible.